# how Install GCC-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: compiling, gcc, arm

I am doing cross compiling on ubuntu20.04. but a errro "/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found" when run it on my arm platform. I install  gcc-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf on ubuntu 20.04 and there is` GLIBC_2.24' on my arm platform.

so, how can i install gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf under ubuntu 20.04 witch source is on ubuntu 16.04.
or, how can I install glbc 2.24 for gcc-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf on ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the needed package manually with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5-cross/gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf_5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf_5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5-cross/gcc-5-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf_5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gcc-5-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf_5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5-cross/gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: i do it. but it maks my desktop not work.

Answer (score 0):

I added Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) to my apt sources:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic universe
```

This old version of Ubuntu contains the GCC in version 4.9:

```
$ apt policy gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi
gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi:
  Installed: 5.3.1-14ubuntu2cross1
  Candidate: 5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1
  Version table:
     5.5.0-12ubuntu1cross1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe arm64 Packages
 *** 5.3.1-14ubuntu2cross1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I installed the `5.3.*` version, because the default `5.5.*` had some version conflicts:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi=5.3*
```

For even older gcc (4.9), I had to go all the way back to Xenial (14.04), and it also worked the same way.